# IE doesn't see CORS headers in response

Tags: javascript, c#, internet-explorer, cors

I have an API which attaches `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the response upon request, as per CORS specs:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
...
```

in `Application_BeginRequest` method.

FF, Chrome and Safari see this and other CORS-related headers, like `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` headers no problem.

On IE, however, not only that the response header is not visible (even though it's being attached at the API server code, I can see that in debug), but the `OPTIONS` preflight request is not visible anywhere too.

Has anyone had any experience with this behavior?

Comment: What do you mean "the OPTIONS preflight request is not visible"? Do you mean the preflight is not being sent by IE? What version of IE?

Comment: IE 10 and 11. I *sometimes* see it after  10-20 retries (the JS code retries the request in case if fails after a short delay).

Answer (score 0):

After lengthy, lengthy investigation and debugging it turned out the problem had nothing to do with CORS at all - IE made it look like it was CORS, but actually the request failed because the API was returning an error message (but with a 200 code).

FML.